# I am trying to extract drive size from drive description in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have files in format below:

```
146GB 10K 2GB FC
23536RPM SATA II 1000GB
NX24 623GB 1587K SA55S 15X3.5 DAE UPG
X 3TB N 15X3.5 DAE UQ
TY 1.8TB 10K SAS 25X2.53 DR
2TB 72PM II FGH DTTR
450GB 15KS 12V 4GB FC UPG
```

How do I get the first drive size(GB OR TB)in GB's ?

The result would look like:

```
146GB 10K 2GB FC                        --->146
23536RPM SATA II 1000GB                 --->1000
NX24 623GB 1587K SA55S 15X3.5 DAE UPG   --->623
X 3TB N 15X3.5 DAE UQ                   --->3000
TY 1.8TB 10K SAS 25X2.53 DR             --->1800
2TB 72PM II FGH DTTR                    --->2000
450GB 15KS 12V 4GB FC UPG               --->450
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '
function check(val){
   val=val~/tb/?val*1024:(val~/gb/?val:"");
   sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",val);
   return val}
{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      value=check(tolower($i));
      if(value)      {  print value; next };
}
print 9999
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder! . How to handle the space between drive size and GB/TB i.e 2 TB 72PM II FGH DTTR --->2000 450 GB 15KS 12V 4GB FC UPG --->450 and if there are no GB/TB in the line iit should return 9999. Can you assist here.

Comment: @Umesh, please check my updated answer now, where if it is NOT finding any GB or TB in any line then it will print `9999` in it, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @Umesh, I also tested it with a sample Input_file(where I have kept a line without TB or GB) and it printed `9999` in it. Also try to encourage people(whoever is helping you) by up-voting their answers as we all are there to learn and help, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Treating only GB and TB :

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne '/(\d+(?:\.\d)*.\d)*)(G|T)B\b/;print $2 eq "T" ? $1*1000  : $1' file
```

or using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '
    {
        match($0,/([0-9.]+)(G|T)B/,a)
        print a[3] == "T" ? a[1]*1000 : a[1]
    }
' file
```

```
146
1000
623
3000
1800
2000
450
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles! . How to handle the space between drive size and GB/TB i.e                                                                                                               2 TB 72PM II FGH DTTR                    --->2000
450 GB 15KS 12V 4GB FC UPG               --->450 and if there are no GB/TB it should return 9999. Can you assist here.

Comment: @Umesh it's extremely important for the sample you provide in your question to be truly representative of your real data. When you post one thing and then later in a comment say "oh but it's not REALLY like that, it's like this..." that's very frustrating to the people trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, exactly.

Comment: Sure , this is my first time in stackoverflow , I will definitly correct myself going forward. Thanks @EdMorton & Gilles.

Answer (score 2):

WIth GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([0-9.]+)([GT])B/,a){ $0=$0 "\t--->" a[1] * (a[2] == "T" ? 1000 : 1) }1' file |
    column -s$'\t' -t
146GB 10K 2GB FC                       --->146
23536RPM SATA II 1000GB                --->1000
NX24 623GB 1587K SA55S 15X3.5 DAE UPG  --->623
X 3TB N 15X3.5 DAE UQ                  --->3000
TY 1.8TB 10K SAS 25X2.53 DR            --->1800
2TB 72PM II FGH DTTR                   --->2000
450GB 15KS 12V 4GB FC UPG              --->450
```

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX **awk**:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
# The code is only for GB and TB drives -- add to regex and logic to
# support more dimensions
match($0, /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? ?[GT]B/) {
    n = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) # Size with dimensioning
    # redimension to GB
    if (n ~ /T/)
        n *= 1000
    # TODO: should 40 spaces be configurable?
    printf("%-40s-->%d\n", $0, n)
}
```